# Setup my own DNS server to support wildcard domains?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, centos, wildcard-subdomain

My registrar doesn't support wildcard domains through their DNS system, but I can define my own DNS Services,

I can't change my registrar (I know, the "why" is beyond the scope of my question :)), and I do want wildcard domains.

**My question is is it possible to setup my own DNS services to support wildcard domains** / bypass my registrar DNS service limitation? **If so, how?**

I know how to configure Apache / httpd.conf to make wildcard domains work, I'm interested in "setting the DNS" part

---

PS. I have a **dedicated box running CentOS 6.4 + Apache 2.2.15**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use some freedns service (eg. http://freedns.afraid.org/) to set up your domain.

Or if your box have 2 IP or your registrar allow to put 2times the same ip you can:

1. install bind on your dedicated box.
2. Create zone, and put some A * records on your domain.
3. Change dns for your domain to your box IP with ns1.yourdomain ns2.yourdomain, ask your registrar how to do that in his panel.

Comment: Another alternative is [Namecheap FreeDNS](https://www.namecheap.com/domains/freedns.aspx) -- https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/597/10/how-can-i-set-up-a-catchall-wildcard-subdomain

You will need to change the name servers to the ones provided by Namecheap.

Comment: @VivekThomas Thanks! that's exactly what I wanted!!!